# Unsure about word embeddings, POS re: using a Neural Net for NLP classification.

Tags: twitter, nlp, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, preprocessor

Im planning on using an NN for sarcasm detection on a number of tweets. Im unsure of how to prepare the word embeddings I will train the NN on. If I tokenize the strings and tag emoticons, capitalisation, user tags, hashtags etc, how do i then combine the resulting strings with word embeddings? do i train the word embeddings on the resulting corpus of tweets?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is hard to identify the core of your question.

Comment: Well im only in the initial stages at the minute. Ive been familiarising myself with NNs and running examples. But its hard to find information on NLP tasks with NNs relevant to mine. Can I ask how you would approach the task? lets say I have 1000 sarcastic tweets. how would I prepare the data to train a neural net with?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by reading some papers on sarcasm detection in twitter, e.g. [Semi-Supervised Recognition of Sarcastic Sentences in Twitter and Amazon](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W10-2914), which uses patterns of content words and high frequency words, or closer to your question [Sarcastic or Not: Word Embeddings to Predict the Literal or Sarcastic
Meaning of Words](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D15-1116) which uses `word2vec`. The latter views the sarcasm detection problem as disambiguation problem of literal and sarcastic meanings of the same word. Perhaps you can employ this approach using the recently published [sense2vec - A Fast and Accurate Method for Word Sense Disambiguation In Neural Word Embeddings](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06388v1.pdf).

Try to use the techniques used in the papers, and when you encounter a *specific* problem ask a question with a minimal working example.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'd already read those first two papers, including many more. Thanks for the word2vec one, hadnt come across it. I'll knuckle down and start working through them again and report back if I have anything specific to ask..